# Why is Pandas .loc changing only one row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
              Open     High      Low    Close       Volume         MA  Status  Portfolio
Date
1958-03-12    42.41    42.41    42.41    42.41    2688889.0    41.3016     1.0      100.0
1958-03-13    42.46    42.46    42.46    42.46    3144444.0    41.3442     1.0        NaN
1958-03-14    42.33    42.33    42.33    42.33    2388889.0    41.3734     1.0        NaN
1958-03-17    42.04    42.04    42.04    42.04    2366667.0    41.4006     1.0        NaN
1958-03-18    41.89    41.89    41.89    41.89    2300000.0    41.4184     1.0        NaN
1958-03-19    42.09    42.09    42.09    42.09    2677778.0    41.4404     1.0        NaN
1958-03-20    42.11    42.11    42.11    42.11    2533333.0    41.4676     1.0        NaN
1958-03-21    42.42    42.42    42.42    42.42    2700000.0    41.5086     1.0        NaN
1958-03-24    42.58    42.58    42.58    42.58    2866667.0    41.5504     1.0        NaN
```

I want the 'Portfolio' column to be calculated as a previous day's value plus the return for the day, if the 'Status' equals 1. I have a line like this:

```
spx_daily.loc['1958-03-13':].loc[spx_daily['Status'] == 1, 'Portfolio'] = ((spx_daily.Close / spx_daily.Close.shift(1))) * spx_daily.Portfolio.shift(1)
```

However, when I run the code the output is like this:

```
                   Open     High      Low    Close       Volume         MA  Status   Portfolio
Date
1958-03-12    42.41    42.41    42.41    42.41    2688889.0    41.3016     1.0  100.000000
1958-03-13    42.46    42.46    42.46    42.46    3144444.0    41.3442     1.0  100.117897
1958-03-14    42.33    42.33    42.33    42.33    2388889.0    41.3734     1.0         NaN
1958-03-17    42.04    42.04    42.04    42.04    2366667.0    41.4006     1.0         NaN
1958-03-18    41.89    41.89    41.89    41.89    2300000.0    41.4184     1.0         NaN
1958-03-19    42.09    42.09    42.09    42.09    2677778.0    41.4404     1.0         NaN
1958-03-20    42.11    42.11    42.11    42.11    2533333.0    41.4676     1.0         NaN
1958-03-21    42.42    42.42    42.42    42.42    2700000.0    41.5086     1.0         NaN
1958-03-24    42.58    42.58    42.58    42.58    2866667.0    41.5504     1.0         NaN
```

Only the first row was calculated. Is that because the operation happens 'all at once' and the remaining rows are detected as being nan?

How should I tackle that while avoiding iterating over rows?

Comment: Operations on a NaN (multiplication, addition etc) will result in a NaN. It's only thanks to the `shift(1)` method that the second row has a value instead of a NaN.

Comment: do you want cumprod?

Comment: So yes, it is because the operation happens "all at once" (in other words: the order isn't defined, and the implicit loop could be bottom-up); it is also the case that things don't happen in-place: a (copy of) the current values are used as input, which includes 8 NaNs.

Comment: please check my answer and tell me if it works @Michal Stefaniak

Comment: check my answer @0 0

Comment: Is your date index datetime type?

Comment: Yes, my date index is datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) + [`Series.cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html)

```
df['Portfolio']=df['Portfolio'].fillna( (df['Close']/df['Close'].shift()).mask(df.Status.ne(1),1) )
df['Portfolio']=df['Portfolio'].cumprod()
print(df)
             Open   High    Low  Close     Volume       MA  Status   Portfolio
Date                                                                          
1958-03-12  42.41  42.41  42.41  42.41  2688889.0  41.3016     1.0  100.000000
1958-03-13  42.46  42.46  42.46  42.46  3144444.0  41.3442     1.0  100.117897
1958-03-14  42.33  42.33  42.33  42.33  2388889.0  41.3734     1.0   99.811365
1958-03-17  42.04  42.04  42.04  42.04  2366667.0  41.4006     1.0   99.127564
1958-03-18  41.89  41.89  41.89  41.89  2300000.0  41.4184     1.0   98.773874
1958-03-19  42.09  42.09  42.09  42.09  2677778.0  41.4404     1.0   99.245461
1958-03-20  42.11  42.11  42.11  42.11  2533333.0  41.4676     1.0   99.292620
1958-03-21  42.42  42.42  42.42  42.42  2700000.0  41.5086     1.0  100.023579
1958-03-24  42.58  42.58  42.58  42.58  2866667.0  41.5504     1.0  100.400849
```

I have use **df** instead **spx_daily**.
I just want you to understand the idea

---

**Checking with a one row with status == 0:**

```
df.iloc[4,6]=0
print(df)
             Open   High    Low  Close     Volume       MA  Status  Portfolio
Date                                                                         
1958-03-12  42.41  42.41  42.41  42.41  2688889.0  41.3016     1.0      100.0
1958-03-13  42.46  42.46  42.46  42.46  3144444.0  41.3442     1.0        NaN
1958-03-14  42.33  42.33  42.33  42.33  2388889.0  41.3734     1.0        NaN
1958-03-17  42.04  42.04  42.04  42.04  2366667.0  41.4006     1.0        NaN
1958-03-18  41.89  41.89  41.89  41.89  2300000.0  41.4184     0.0        NaN
1958-03-19  42.09  42.09  42.09  42.09  2677778.0  41.4404     1.0        NaN
1958-03-20  42.11  42.11  42.11  42.11  2533333.0  41.4676     1.0        NaN
1958-03-21  42.42  42.42  42.42  42.42  2700000.0  41.5086     1.0        NaN
1958-03-24  42.58  42.58  42.58  42.58  2866667.0  41.5504     1.0        NaN
```

---

```
df['Portfolio']=df['Portfolio'].fillna( (df['Close']/df['Close'].shift()).mask(df.Status.ne(1),1) )
df['Portfolio']=df['Portfolio'].cumprod()
print(df)
                 Open   High    Low  Close     Volume       MA  Status   Portfolio
Date                                                                          
1958-03-12  42.41  42.41  42.41  42.41  2688889.0  41.3016     1.0  100.000000
1958-03-13  42.46  42.46  42.46  42.46  3144444.0  41.3442     1.0  100.117897
1958-03-14  42.33  42.33  42.33  42.33  2388889.0  41.3734     1.0   99.811365
1958-03-17  42.04  42.04  42.04  42.04  2366667.0  41.4006     1.0   99.127564
1958-03-18  41.89  41.89  41.89  41.89  2300000.0  41.4184     0.0   99.127564
1958-03-19  42.09  42.09  42.09  42.09  2677778.0  41.4404     1.0   99.600840
1958-03-20  42.11  42.11  42.11  42.11  2533333.0  41.4676     1.0   99.648167
1958-03-21  42.42  42.42  42.42  42.42  2700000.0  41.5086     1.0  100.381744
1958-03-24  42.58  42.58  42.58  42.58  2866667.0  41.5504     1.0  100.760365
```

Comment: Thank you, that does it. However, as you might have guessed, the 'Status' not always equals '1', sometimes it's '0' in which case I would like the 'Portfolio' value to equal the value of previous row.

Comment: Thanks for the patience, I have updated the solution :) Please tell me if it works. If so, consider accepting or voting my answer. In that case, if this still does not work, could you update the data frame with some row of status == 0?